# OrderBy with Swedish letters

Tags: c#, sorting, letters

I have a list of my custom class Customer and I want to sort them alphabetically by Title. 
So I wrote

```
myList = myList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Title).ToList<Customer>();
```

Now the problem is that this method doesn't support the Swedish way of sorting the letters å, ä, ö. They should appear at the end after the letter z but they don't.

So I made a workaround method that replaces the Swedish letters before the ordering and then changes them back afterwords. It looks like this but it is quite slow. Can somebody think of a better way?

```
private List<Customer> OrderBySwedish(List<Customer> myList)
    {
        foreach (var customer in myList)
        {
            customer.Title = customer.Title.Replace("å", "zzz1").Replace("ä", "zzz2").Replace("ö", "zzz3").Replace("Å", "Zzz1").Replace("Ä", "Zzz2").Replace("Ö", "Zzz3");
        }

        myList= myList.OrderBy(x => x.Title).ToList<Customer>();

        foreach (var customer in myList)
        {
            customer.Title = customer.Title.Replace("zzz1", "å").Replace("zzz2", "ä").Replace("zzz3", "ö").Replace("Zzz1", "Å").Replace("Zzz2", "Ä").Replace("Zzz3", "Ö");
        }
        return myList;
    }
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use culture specific `StringComparer`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846215/how-do-i-get-linq-to-order-according-to-culture).

```
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("sv-SE");
var result = myList.OrderByDescending(x => 
               x.Title, StringComparer.Create(culture, false));
```

Answer (score 4):

Set the [Thread.CurrentCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentculture%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) property to the correct culture.

Answer (score 1):

I my case:
_My sorting list have value was encoded. This make my order incorrect. Add decoded solving my problems !

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I found for a somewhat similar problem was to have a secondary field that held the converted version of the data.
In my case, we had `person.Name` and `person.SearchName`, where `SearchName` was `Name` converted to have no diacritics.

But this was only the best approach (AFAIK) because we wanted a speedy db search/filtering and then instantiating only the relevant results.
If you already have the objects in memory I would advise going with one of the other approaches; and **not** this one.