# OrderBy ignoring accented letters

Tags: c#, sorting, lambda, expression, letters

I want a method like `OrderBy()` that always orders ignoring accented letters and to look at them like non-accented. I already tried to override `OrderBy()` but seems I can't do that because that is a static method.

So now I want to create a custom lambda expression for `OrderBy()`, like this:

```
public static IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> ToOrderBy<TSource, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
{
    if(source == null)
        return null;

    var seenKeys = new HashSet<TKey>();

    var culture = new CultureInfo("pt-PT");
    return source.OrderBy(element => seenKeys.Add(keySelector(element)), 
                          StringComparer.Create(culture, false));
}
```

However, I'm getting this error:

> Error 2   The type arguments for method
>   'System.Linq.Enumerable.OrderBy<TSource,TKey>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>,
>   System.Func<TSource,TKey>,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IComparer<TKey>)' cannot be inferred from
>   the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Seems it doesn't like `StringComparer`. How can I solve this?

**Note:**

I already tried to use `RemoveDiacritics()` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359827/ignoring-accented-letters-in-string-comparison) but I don't know how to use that method in this case. So I tried to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229445/orderby-with-swedish-letters) which seems nice too.

Comment: Are you using Linq2Sql or LinqObjects ?

Comment: What is the HashSet for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved! I was getting that error because to use `StringComparer` the element to sort in `OrderBy()` expression that element needs to be a `string`.

So when I know that element is a string I cast to a string and I use the `RemoveDiacritics()` method to ignore the accented letters and to look at them like non-accented.

```
public static IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> ToOrderBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
{
    if(!source.SafeAny())
        return null;

    return source.OrderBy(element => Utils.RemoveDiacritics(keySelector(element).ToString()));
}
```

To garantee the `RemoveDiacritics()` works fine I add a `HtmlDecode()` line.

```
public static string RemoveDiacritics(string text)
{
    if(text != null)
        text = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(text);

    string formD = text.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (char ch in formD)
    {
        UnicodeCategory uc = CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(ch);
        if (uc != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark)
        {
            sb.Append(ch);
        }
    }

    return sb.ToString().Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormC);
}
```

Comment: There is absolutely no need to implement your `ToOrderBy`. If you have a string enumeration named `mystrings` you can simply call `mystrings.OrderBy(RemoveDiacritics, StringComparer.Create(culture, false))`

Comment: @RenéVogt I know but I want to performance that because my project is huge and I don't want to do that modification in the all project

Comment: @RenéVogt to use `ToOrderBy()` in my solution I only need to do Ctrl + F and replace `.OrderBy(` with `.ToOrderBy(` and in the future if I need to change something in this logic I only need to change in one place and not in the entire project. Here's my performance. For the exception I have a `SafeAny()` method where I check if is not null and have any element.

Answer (score 2):

`OrderBy` takes a `keySelector` as first argument. This `keySelector` should be a `Func<string,T>`. So you need a method that takes a string and returns a *value by which your enumeration should be sorted*.

Unfortunatly I'm not sure how to determine if a character is a "accented letter". The `RemoveDiacritics` doesn't work for my `é`.

So let's assume you have a method called `IsAccentedLetter` that determines if a character is an accented letter:

```
public bool IsAccentedLetter(char c)
{
    // I'm afraid this does NOT really do the job
    return CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c) == UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark;
}
```

So you can sort your list like that:

```
string[] myStrings = getStrings(); // whereever your strings come from
var ordered = myStrings.OrderBy(s => new string(s.Select(c => 
    IsAccentedLetter(c) ? ' ' : c).ToArray()), StringComparer.Create(culture, false));
```

The lambda expression takes a string and returns the same string, but replaced the accented letters with an empty space.
`OrderBy` now sorts your enumeration by these strings, and so "ignores" the accented letters.

**UPDATE:** If you have a working method `RemoveDiacritics(string s)` that returns the strings with the accented letters replaced as you want, you may simply call `OrderBy` like this:

```
string[] mystrings = getStrings();
var ordered = myStrings.OrderBy(RemoveDiacritics, StringComparer.Create(culture, false));
```

Comment: that logic gives me the error `'TSource' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'TSource' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`. Besides you are replacing the accented letter with a white space and I want the accented letter to be trated like a non-accented letter.

Comment: @Ninita oh this was a misunderstanding: my `source´ was meant to be your original list. I did not intend to implement my own `ToOrderBy` extension at all, this is not necessary! In your solution, you don't need your `ToOrderBy`, you can just call `mystrings.OrderBy(RemoveDiacritics, StringComparer,Create(culture, false)`