# ListView SortDescriptions with nordic/special characters

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, listview

When sorting a ListView with items starting with special characters (Åå/Ää/Öö) they don't end up where they should.

[image: 'Testing' should come before 'Ö:Last place!!']

Do I have to implement a custom sorting method or is there a better way?

If yes on the custom sort, how do I simply sort by ABC, including special characters?

Edit:
This is my current sort method:

```
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Width="150">
                    <GridViewColumn.Header>
                        <GridViewColumnHeader Tag="Name" Click="SortByColumns">Name</GridViewColumnHeader>
                    </GridViewColumn.Header>
                </GridViewColumn>
```

...

```
    private void SortByColumns(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewColumnHeader column = (sender as GridViewColumnHeader);
        string sortBy = column.Tag.ToString();
        if (listViewSortCol != null)
        {
            AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(listViewSortCol).Remove(listViewSortAdorner);
            siteListView.Items.SortDescriptions.Clear();
        }

        ListSortDirection newDir = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
        if (listViewSortCol == column && listViewSortAdorner.Direction == newDir)
            newDir = ListSortDirection.Descending;

        listViewSortCol = column;
        listViewSortAdorner = new SortAdorner(listViewSortCol, newDir);
        AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(listViewSortCol).Add(listViewSortAdorner);
        siteListView.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(sortBy, newDir));
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get LINQ to order according to culture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846215/how-do-i-get-linq-to-order-according-to-culture)

Comment: Are you sorting in `ListView` or in your `ViewModel`?

Comment: How are you currently sorting your ListView?

Comment: @XAMlMAX ListView

Comment: @mm8 check my edit

Comment: You might want to use the link provided and filter the data at view model level. Your code is fine and I can't find anything Culture specific for `SortDescriptions`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to set the `Language` property of the `DataGrid` to your language:

```
<DataGrid Language="sv" ...>
```

If you set or bind the `ItemsSource` of the `ListView` to an `IList`, you could use a custom `IComparer` to implement some completely custom sorting logic.

Please refer to the following sample code.

```
public class StringComparer<T> : IComparer where T : class
{
    private static readonly CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("sv-SE");
    private string _propertyName;
    private int _direction;


    public StringComparer(string propertyName, ListSortDirection direction)
    {
        _propertyName = propertyName;
        _direction = direction == ListSortDirection.Descending ? 1 : -1;
    }

    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        if (x == null && y == null)
            return 0;
        else if (x == null)
            return -1;
        else if (y == null)
            return 1;
        else
        {
            PropertyInfo pi = typeof(T).GetProperty(_propertyName);
            if (pi == null)
                return 0;

            object a = pi.GetValue(x);
            object b = pi.GetValue(y);

            if (a == null && b == null)
                return 0;
            else if (a == null)
                return -1;
            else if (b == null)
                return 1;

            return string.Compare(a.ToString(), b.ToString(), false, culture) * _direction;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
private void SortByColumns(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewColumnHeader column = (sender as GridViewColumnHeader);
    string sortBy = column.Tag.ToString();
    if (listViewSortCol != null)
    {
        AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(listViewSortCol).Remove(listViewSortAdorner);
        siteListView.Items.SortDescriptions.Clear();
    }

    ListSortDirection newDir = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
    if (listViewSortCol == column /*&& listViewSortAdorner.Direction == newDir*/)
        newDir = ListSortDirection.Descending;

    listViewSortCol = column;
    listViewSortAdorner = new SortAdorner(listViewSortCol, newDir);
    AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(listViewSortCol).Add(listViewSortAdorner);

    ListCollectionView lvi = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(siteListView.ItemsSource) as ListCollectionView;
    if (lvi != null)
    {
        lvi.CustomSort = new StringComparer<MyTuple>(sortBy, newDir);
    }
    else
        siteListView.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(sortBy, newDir));

}
```